Computing the outer volume of a sphere intersection
I have to compute $\iiint_E x \, dV$ in this region:
$$
E = \{ (x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 1 \ \text{and} \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2x \}
$$
Which is the outer volume of the intersection of two spheres.
I tried to solve it using spherical coordinates set in the origin. What I tried to do was first find the intersections of the spheres, in order to find the limiting values of $\phi$ and $\theta$. First for $\phi$, looking from a perspective at the $xz$ plane, I found that the spheres intersect at two angles: $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}$. For $\theta$, observing the intersections of the projections of both spheres in the $xy$ plane, I found that they happen at the angles $\frac{-\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$. And then, using the second condition, I found the possible values for $\rho$. What I came up with was:

\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \phi \leq \frac{5\pi}{6}, \\
-\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}, \\
1 \leq \rho \leq 2\sin\phi\cos\theta.
\end{cases}
Then the triple integral renders:
$$
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} 
\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}} 
\int_{1}^{2\sin\phi\cos\theta} 
\rho^3 \sin^2\phi \cos\theta \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta
$$
Which is not the answer. I would like to know what was my error. Thanks.

The obvious culprit (for the sequence of integration you chose)
is your bounds on $\phi$.
Perform a sanity check. Let $\rho=1$, $\theta=\frac\pi3$, and $\phi=\frac\pi6$,
which according to your integral is a point on the boundary of your region of integration. Then
\begin{align}
x = \sin\phi\cos\theta &= \frac14, \\
y = \sin\phi\sin\theta &= \frac{\sqrt3}4, \\
z = \cos\phi &= \frac{\sqrt3}2, \\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1 > \frac12 = 2x.
\end{align}
So this point is not even close to the true region of integration.
Your error is you looked at the values of $\theta$ only when $\phi=\frac\pi2$,
and you looked at the values of $\phi$ only when $\theta=0$.
You did not consider how the values of $\theta$ or $\phi$ might be restricted in any other case.
This is like integrating in Cartesian coordinates over the disk inside the unit circle by merely observing that $-1\leq x\leq1$ and $-1\leq y\leq1$.
You can correct your integral by computing the actual minimum and maximum $\phi$ for each value of $\theta$ other than $0$,
but I think a better alternative is to use the $x$ axis as the axis of your spherical coordinates instead of using the $z$ axis.

Continuing with spherical coordinates using the $z$ axis as the axis of the spherical coordinate system, consider an arbitrary $\theta$ such that $-\frac\pi3 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi3$.
Now consider the minimum and maximum values of $\phi$ for this $\theta$. At those values of $\phi$, and at $\rho=1$, we get a point on the intersection of the surfaces of the two spheres. That intersection is a circle whose $x$ coordinate is always $\frac12$. Therefore
$$ \sin\phi\cos\theta = \frac12 $$
and it follows that the two possible values of $\phi$ are the two values between $0$ and $\pi$ for which $\sin\phi = \frac12\sec\theta$,
namely $\phi = \arcsin\left(\frac12\sec\theta\right)$
and $\phi = \pi - \arcsin\left(\frac12\sec\theta\right)$.
So those are your bounds of integration, and your integral is
$$
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} 
\int_{\arcsin\left(\frac12\sec\theta\right)}^{\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac12\sec\theta\right)} 
\int_{1}^{2\sin\phi\cos\theta} 
\rho^3 \sin^2\phi \cos\theta
 \, \mathrm d\rho \, \mathrm d\phi \, \mathrm d\theta.
$$
Contrast this with the approach where we use the $x$ axis as the axis of our spherical coordinates. Then the circle where the two spheres intersect is given by $\phi = \frac\pi3$, $\rho = 1$, and all values of $\theta$. You'll be able to integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ with no other restriction because the axis of your coordinate system is the axis of rotational symmetry of the region you're integrating over.

If you're still having trouble visualizing how this works, try integrating  $\iiint_{E'} z \, \mathrm dV$ in the region
$$
E' = \{ (x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 1 \ \text{and} \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2z \}.
$$
That is, relabel your coordinate axes so that the $x$ axis becomes the $z$ axis. You should get exactly the same result from this integral as for the original problem if both are integrated correctly.

Could you please tell me how to compute those values for $\phi$? I lack the mathematical visualization to solve the problem.

I think it's a waste of time to continue down that path. Try measuring $\phi$ from the $x$ axis instead of from the $z$ axis; that's much simpler. But I'll see what we get for your integral for the sake of completeness.

Thanks for the very complete answer. I understand now my mistake. Just an addendum, when you said to try measuring $\phi$ from the $x$ axis, I realized it would be easier to just use cylindrical coordinates with respect to the $x$ axis instead of spherical. The insights are much appreciated.
